# Create a virtual machine and connect to it command line

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm running an Ubuntu 14.04 server, and would like it to also run another 14.04 server instance in a VM on it. (I need to use two VPNs on the same machine simultaneously)

I've tried using both KVM and virtual box, but I was never able to figure out how to ssh into the server once it was running. Almost all of the tutorials I've found use the GUI tools or tell you how to create a VM in the command line and then tell you to VNC into it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer from StackOverflow, it was specific to windows but the commands are the same. You just need to enable port forwarding, and it should work just fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-virtualbox-ubuntu-guest-externally-through-a-windows-host

Comment: This didn't seem to work, I never made a user or set a password though.

Comment: How can you ssh into a server without a username and password? :)